# Create new project in VS 2013 to be compatible with 2010

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, webforms, visual-studio-2013, project

At home I have VS 2013, but at my college they use VS 2010 and we have to make WebForms project.
Can I create new project in 2013 so that it can be opened in 2010?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK no, even projects created in 2010 have to be converted to a higher version, if you want to open them in 2013.. You can however open individual source files without any issues. It's just the project file that's problematic. I'm afraid you'd have to have installed 2010 as well (you can have multiple versions of VS installed on one system).